# Firefox returns blank $viewValue when type="number" with space in field

Tags: angularjs, forms, firefox, directive

I'm trying to setup a credit card entry field, and I need to be able to separate the digit-groups with a space. But on a mobile device, I want the number keyboard to appear, so I'm using `input[type="number"]` instead of just `input[type="text"]`.

Currently, when I test on Chrome it's working. The $viewValue appearing in the directive for the credit card field shows the 16-digit number (Angular even auto-removes the spaces because of number type field).

But in Firefox, as soon as you type a space, $viewValue returns as "" (even though the field value is "5555 5555 5555 4444").

Is there any way to make this work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Wow Maybe this a serious Mozilla Bug, with no solution for now, then you may apply other ways to resolve this.

1. Use mask (lose number on mobile): Try Plugins, library like this http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ , the bad user loses the PAD NUMBER on mobile devices.
2. To keep input number (complex only for fun): Make a input type hidden, then when the user type on number field, fill the hidden input with the value.
3. Use text field (best way): yes number is the new era on HTML5, but users don't care that for now, yeah show only numbers with the pad (like most apps) is awesome, now ask is really necesary?
4. Dynamic Form JS: verify the browser version, if Wild Mozilla appears, change type number to type text ;)

Good luck !!

best regards from http://elporfirio.com

Comment: I've been thinking #3 and #4 as well. I think Mobile will mostly be Chrome (Android) and Safari (iPhone) anyway, so Firefox users will most likely be desktop and won't have a mobile keyboard anyway.